Invariance under measure preserving functions
Let $W: [0,1]^k \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel-measurable function such that $W$ is invariant under any measure-preserving function $\varphi: [0,1] \to [0,1]$, i.e. for $W^\varphi(x_1, \dots, x_k) := W(\varphi(x_1), \dots, \varphi(x_k))$ we have $W^\varphi = W$ almost everywhere w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. Does this imply that $W$ is a.e. constant?
While it seems intuitive to me that this should hold, my attempts to prove this have been unsuccessful so far and I could also imagine there being degenerate counterexamples. So far, I tried a proof by contradiction: If $W$ is not a.e. constant, there exist disjoint measurable $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $\lambda^k(W^{-1}(A)) > 0$, $\lambda^k(W^{-1}(B)) > 0$. It would be nice now to find subsets of $W^{-1}(A), W^{-1}(B)$ of positive measure for which some $\varphi$ can be constructed that "switches" these two subsets. However, I don't see how such a construction would work without additional assumptions on $W$, such as continuity.
